# Ricci flat metric on pair (X,D)

Tags: complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds, divisors, calabi-yau

Let $(X,\omega)$ be a Calabi-Yau variety and $D$ be a simple normal crossing divisor on $X$ with conic singularities with cone angle $2\pi\theta$, $0<\theta<1$ such that $K_X+D>0$, then is there any Ricci flat metric on it

Comment: See papers of Tian with Yau

Comment: @HassanJolany they solved it for $\theta<\frac{1}{2}$